# GUI-based measure distance on screen rectangular selection

Tags: linux

I'm looking for a Linux based tool that does exactly what the [Page Ruler](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-ruler/jlpkojjdgbllmedoapgfodplfhcbnbpn) Chrome Extension does, but will permit me to zoom in the browser so I can align the tool with the edge of an element.

I don't want to have to touch the command-line to the operate the tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind two programs at once, you may be able to use [Arakis/gcaliper](https://github.com/Arakis/gcaliper) for your purposes.

I installed it moments ago and it resembles quite closely a windows program called Screen Calipers.

[image: gcaliper]

One aspect of your requirement, that of being able to zoom for more precise measurements, isn't a feature of any of the screen rulers or screen calipers I've found. However, I also installed a magnifier program known to its friends and enemies alike as [Kmag](https://www.kde.org/applications/utilities/kmag/).

[image]

It's rather simplistic, but has a number of features that may make it useful to you. Foremost is the ability to chase/shadow/follow the mouse. In my test, I was able to move the left jaw of gcaliper by holding near the bottom, to get one pixel precision, then move to the right lower jaw to find the opposite edge.

gcaliper will allow you to rotate the tool to one degree resolution and also snaps to 45° resolution with the shift or control key (I forget which).

If you use Kmag for zoom, be sure to set the Mouse button to follow your pointer, and also I'd recommend to change the pointer resolution to very high. At the lowest setting, the jumps are perhaps greater than ten pixel steps, while at the highest, it's a single pixel movement. I did not notice a deterioration of performance in the highest resolution.

Comment: Although I haven't tested it yet, this combination should provide exactly what I'm looking for.  I was beginning to get frustrated about the possibility that Linux would fail to support (with known, public software) such a trivial use-case.  Many thanks